# Javascript paints images over top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am using node.js + socket.io to try and make a multiplier HTML5 canvas game. Unfortunately every time I go to draw all of the players, all the images end up on top of each other.

```
socket.on('drawPlayers', function(players){
    context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , gameWidth , gameHeight ); //clear canvas

    for(var i=0; i<players.length; i++){
      var cur = players[i];
      var playerSprite = new Image();
      playerSprite.onload = function() {
        return context.drawImage(playerSprite, cur.x, cur.y);
      };
      playerSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';
      console.log("drawing player "+cur.un+" at ("+cur.x+","+cur.y+")");
    }
  });
```

The console.log() will log the different x and y values correctly, but all of the images end up on top of each other.

```
function player(id,username){
  this.id = id;
  this.un = username;
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 801);
  this.src = 'images/mobile_md_logo.png';
}
```

I

Comment: Try putting some debugging inside `playerSprite.onload = function() {`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1451009. Despite the placement of the declarations, `cur` and `playerSprite` are only declared once and shared by all iterations of the loop. [You'll want a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) so each iteration has its own `cur` and `playerSprite`.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Lonowski is right. For each of the onload triggers, `cur` points to the same player, the last one. There is only one `cur` that exists inside `drawPlayers` event handler.

Use this to separate the scope of `cur` from one that is in the loop:

```
function draw(sprite,cur){
  return function() {
    context.drawImage(sprite, cur.x, cur.y);
  };
}
```

Then call it from inside the loop

```
for(var i=0; i<players.length; i++){
  var cur = players[i];
  var playerSprite = new Image();
  playerSprite.onload = draw(playerSprite,cur);
  playerSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';
  console.log("drawing player "+cur.un+" at ("+cur.x+","+cur.y+")");
}
```